# Mapbox Layout Visibility Flickering

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

On the website below, I have two layers for each month from 2015 to 2020 (one for routes, one for airports), and when the date slider is moved, I set the visibility of the new layer to visible and the visibility of the previously active layer to none. However, there is a noticeable lag time where the previous layers disappear and the new layer appears, leading to a flicker effect when play is pressed. I'm setting the visibility of the new layer to visible BEFORE I set the visibility of the previous layer to none, so I'm not sure why this happens. Any help would be appreaciated.

https://picrazy2.github.io/flightlog/

Comment: You might provide a bit of code to help us help you. It might be unlikely that someone first reverse engineers the code of your website before providing some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The delay is because the newly visible layer has to be loaded from the server.

One workaround (with the caveat of a lot more network traffic in general) is to have every layer visible all the time, but very low opacity (say 0.01). Then, instead of setting a layer visible, change its opacity to 1, and change the previous one to 0.01.